# Upload .HTML Jupyter Markdown to Git pages

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, github-pages

I was wondering if it's possible to upload HTML markdown files(Jupyter) to git pages. I am able to host .md files but not .html files. If I upload loan_grant.md to files folder it works but if I upload loan_grant.html I get a 404 error while hosting on github pages.
(/files/loan_grant)